# Unit test for web api action method responds while exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I was trying to write some unit tests for an web api action method while exception. So below my action method

```
[Route("{userName}/{searchCriteria}")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Events(string accountNumber, string searchCriteria)
{
    try
    {
        bool isInputValid = _inputValidation.IsTrackingEventInputValid(accountNumber, searchCriteria);
        if (isInputValid)
        {
            return OK ("my data");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ae)
    {
        return new ResponseMessageResult(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ExceptionHandlingMessages.InvalidArgumentException));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new ResponseMessageResult(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ExceptionHandlingMessages.InternalServerError));
    }
}
```

I want to check responds status code and responds messages while exception occurs. But problem is as soon as my execution hits `ResponseMessageResult` code it throws another `ArgumentNullException` saying `Value cannot be null.Parameter name: request`. Because of that control never returns to my unit test method.

My unit test method as

```
[TestMethod]
public void Events()
{
    _mockInputValidation.Setup(x => x.IsTrackingEventInputValid(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
    //act
    IHttpActionResult actionResult = _trackingEventController.Events(string.Empty, string.Empty);
    //assert
}
```

I also tries putting `[ExpectedException(type)]` but not much helpful

how can I solve this

Comment: If you want to test the return values in the `catch` block, just throw an exception in `_inputValidation.IsTrackingEventInputValid`.  I don't remember the actual syntax but changing the mock to `_mockInputValidation.Setup(x => x.IsTrackingEventInputValid(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Throws(new ArgumentException());` should allow you to get the first `ResponseMessageResult`.

Comment: Show how you new up the controller. Most probably the request is null

Comment: I'd question the value of unit testing an action method explicitly - their behaviour depends on lots of external framework setup. You'd be better served minimizing the behaviour inside the action methods (push it behind interfaces) and test end-to-end with acceptance tests that actually hit the endpoints with HTTP requests.

Comment: I don't have a problem with unit testing controllers, but i'd lose the try/catch block and just return the ResponseMessageResult without throwing and catching within the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your code to try and avoid throwing exceptions in your actions. Let the exception handler/filter handle them (cross-cutting concerns). Your original issue could have happened if you did not provide a proper request message for unit test.

```
[Route("{userName}/{searchCriteria}")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Events(string accountNumber, string searchCriteria) {
    bool isInputValid = _inputValidation.IsTrackingEventInputValid(accountNumber, searchCriteria);
    if (isInputValid) {
        return Ok("my data");
    } else {
        return BadRequest(ExceptionHandlingMessages.InvalidArgumentException);
    }
}
```

And then for the particular test case

```
[TestMethod]
public void IsTrackingEventInputValid_When_False_Should_Return_BadRequest() {
    //Arrange
    _mockInputValidation.Setup(x => x.IsTrackingEventInputValid(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
    var expected = ExceptionHandlingMessages.InvalidArgumentException;
    //Act
    var actionResult = _trackingEventController.Events(string.Empty, string.Empty) as BadRequestErrorMessageResult;
    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actionResult.Message);
}
```